# plastic scm Trying to import rep_1 from one installation to another

Tags: sql-server, plasticscm

I have an instance of plastic installed on my local machine version 5.0.44.519.
This instance is using SQL Server backend.
In here i have several repositories.

rep_1
rep_2
rep_6

now i have backed up these repositories with no problem.

the problem now is that when i go to restore the rep_ databases onto the other plastic instance on the development server i have problems.

the plastic installed on the dev server already had some repositories in it but thats ok, they are rep_24, rep_35 etc. etc. no conflicts.

i can restore the databases onto the dev server no problem.
my problem is that i also need to restore the repositories database onto the dev server plastic otherwise i cannot view the restored rep_ databases.

but the plastic on the server already has a repositories database with values in there, so i cannot restore over it otherwise i will lost whats there.

i would just like to know how i can restore the rep_ databases into plastic without having to restore the repositories database

Answer (score 1):

if you have the database files, you can just relink them to the server using the next command:

```
$> cm addrep

Connect an existing repository by adding its database.

Usage:

    cm addrepository | addrep db_file rep_name repsvr_spec

    db_file             The name of the database file on the database backend.
    rep_name            The name of the repository.
    repsvr_spec         Repository server specification:
                        [repserver:]svr_name:svr_port
```